# How do I efficiently convert pandas dataframe to image array?

Tags: python, pandas, image, numpy, dataframe

I have a big pandas dataframe with columns X,Y, and I. X and Y are pixel coordinates, I is, let's say, an intensity value between 0 and 255 which I want to be shown at the corresponding X and Y position.

There is not an entry for each pixel of the image, so all pixels' I values that are not listed in the dataframe are set to 0.

Therefore, I initialized an two-dimensional array `img` with the image dimensions. Then, I already tried something like

```py
img.at[df.X,df.Y] = df.I
```

which does not work. I think a simple `for`-loop can solve this problem, but I wonder if there is a more efficient way to do this (e.g. call a *fancy numpy/opencv/whatever function I don't know...*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is probably to use `scipy.sparse` arrays, as [`coo_matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html) is built identically to your inputs.

```
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix

sparse_image = coo_matrix((df.I, (df.X, df.Y)), shape = image.shape)
image = sparse_image.todense()
```

`coo_matrix` also has some nice functionalities if your `I` values are being accumulated before this step.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) function of Pandas like this:

```
df.pivot('Y', 'X', 'I').values
```

which will result in something like this:

```
# array([[ 255,  34],
#       [  56,  nan]])
```

Then you simply need to replace the `nan` value with 0.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this perfectly works. However, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57090228/1688285) is much more faster, at least on my hardware (dataframe with 15 millions entries -> your solution ~0.7 seconds, using `coo_matrix` ~0.02 seconds).

Comment: You can also just do `df.pivot_table('Y', 'X', 'I', fill_value = 0).values`, which also allows accumulation (much more flexibly than `coo_matrix` even)